# How to calculate current sharing between two different voltage souces in a parallel circuit?

Tags: power-supply, current

In a parallel circuit consisting of a 14V, 150A alternator maintaining a fully charged 12V, 800 CCA battery - How do I calculate how much current the alternator provides and how much current the battery provides if I put on a `.12 ohm` load?

**Clarification**

`.12 ohm` load for 5 seconds for testing purposes.

Comment: This is going to depend on the and the impedance of the alternator and battery, as well as any other impedances present. With zero impedances the alternator and battery will only current share if they are *EXACTLY* the same voltage which will never happen. What will happen is the alternator will have a higher voltage than the battery and thus try to charge the battery while also supplying the load. You cannot charge and discharge a battery at the same time. If you don't know the impedances, then you should assume the the scenario I described where the alternator supplies everything.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this information? The reason I ask, is that the battery and the alternator are typically dynamic sources and if your 0.12 ohm load is actually a motor (possibly a starter, perhaps?), the problem is quite complex and time-variant.

Comment: and @MOSFET I apologize, My question was for a 5 second test. I updated my question.

Comment: What is your load?

Comment: .12 ohm load which of course at 12v would be 100A for 5 seconds. I do understand that if the alternator and battery were both 12V, Each would supply 50A. If I understand correctly, from what has been said, It blows my mind that that a 14 volt alternator would bear ALL the current load.

Comment: @MOSFET Not to be X Y question...This is the load a battery tester uses.

Comment: OK, assuming you are using a resistor, yes, 12V across push 100A through it. But your assumption that a 12V alternator and a 12V battery would both share 50A a piece is incorrect in the real world. Both these devices have a source impedance that has to be considered. A real 150A alternator will bear all the current because, assuming it has sufficient RPMs, will put out ~14.4V and dominates the battery. This makes sense cause it also has to charge the battery. Will it be all the current? No, but certainly most of it if it's healthy.

Comment: @stumblebee Also, to complicate things, the battery has time-variant characteristics at high load where it's output will tend to "fade" over the engine starting cycle. So your question is not so innocent - it's only trivial with a bunch of assumptions that live in a theoretical framework. Realistically, you would clamp a DC ammeter on it and just measure it. If you want better than that, measure the current of both the alternator and battery vs time on a 2 channel scope to understand the dynamics. Again, why are these quantities important to you? What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: @MOSFET I'm sorry I asked. I relent 

Comment: @stumblebee I'm not trying to discourage you. I'm trying to explain why your question is complicated to answer with certainty. It's not a "textbook question" when you include all the real factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the alternator works properly in a modern vehicle, it provides all the current. If fully charged, the battery is floating, and the alternator is a stiffer source. The battery is there to start the vehicle, recharge quickly, and then float until needed. If the load demands more current than the alternator can provide when running, the voltage sags, and the battery supplies the missing current to keep the voltage up. It is self-regulating via Ohms Law.

Float voltage = 13.8 volts / .012 Ohms = 115 amps from the alternator while the battery floats.

Edit note: The vehicle alternator is a DC power source with precision voltage regulation. They use the same precision electronic voltage regulators as DC power supplies and battery chargers. The alternator voltage regulator is set to 13.8 volts, and when the battery is fully charged, its terminal voltage equals 13.8 volts. The battery and alternator voltage are equal, resulting in no current flow. The battery is FLOATING. When there is a demand for current, the voltage regulator turns up the alternator output to maintain 13.8 volts. The voltage at the battery terminals never changes; thus, no current flows from the battery.

Every DC power plant used in telecom, data centers, radio towers, CATV, and other critical mission systems follows the same principle. You set the output voltage of the rectifiers (or alternator) to the batteries' 100% SOC float voltage. The rectifiers supply the load equipment with power while the batteries float. If power is lost, the batteries supply the load seamlessly. When power is restored, the rectifiers go into current limit to charge the batteries and supply the load with power.

The voltage regulators in the alternator maintain 13.8 volts on the battery. The battery does not see the load, so it sits there and floats until needed. The alternator is at a higher energy state, making it the stiffer source.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I clarified my question, also consider the comment I'm about to make below my question.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. Time has nothing to do with it. The vehicle voltage regulator maintains the voltage at the battery, so it just floats.

Answer (score 3):

The alternator voltage is rectified obtaining a double half-wave which is then capacitively filtered so the resulting voltage is composed of a direct component plus a ripple. Assuming that the voltage produced by the generator is continuous, examination of the circuit gives the following results:

[image]